# Multiple domains for the same site in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console

I have a website that I host with multiple domains. I have them set up in Google Webmaster Tools. They look like this:

[image: All the same website]

I have set the preferred domain to "burlingameautoclinic.com" for all the properties that allow it (burlingameautoclinic.net, for example, has no option to set the preferred domain to burlingameautoclinic.com).

After doing this, I would expect these 5 properties to collapse down to one entry, where I can see all the stats for this domain.

Am I doing this wrong? Should I instead remove all but one of these properties from Webmaster Tools and let Google figure out what my canonical domain is from the 301 redirects I have set up on the other domains? If I do this, will links to the other domains be counted in the stats for my preferred domain?

Answer (score 2):

The preferred domain is to set whether you prefer www or non-www. Read here : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en

If you are redirecting your extra domains to the one main domain then Google will indeed figure it out and the extra domains wont be indexed in the long run (if already) Any link value that the extra domains have may be partially transferred, though you would be best to encourage links for your main (preferred) domain.